# Passing Params to Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, parameters

I'm building my first `gem`. I'm trying to access all the parameters when a view loads, and then assign them to my module methods.

What should happen is when I visit `appurl.com?name=elijah`

and then run `MyGem.name` it should return `elijah`

Here's my gem

```
#my_gem/lib/my_gem.rb
module MyGem

    def self.name
      params[:name]
    end

end
```

How do I access the params of wherever I'm calling my gem from? Do I have to pass it in as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to pass them into something in your gem.  Your gem can't see the `params` method in `ActionController`.

What are you trying to accomplish?  We may be able to suggest a better approach.

If you're just experimenting, try something like this:

```
module MyGem
  class Something

    def initialize(params)
      @params = params
    end

    def method_missing(symbol, *ids)
      @params[symbol] || super
    end

  end
end
```

This will pull items from the params hash given to it, if they are available as a symbol in the hash.  So you could do something like:

```
x = MyGem::Something.new(params)
x.first_name
=> 'xyz'
x.last_name
=> 'abc'
```

Comment: More trying to experiment than anything (because it'd be easier to just do it in the view). The gem should initialize and parse all of the parameters from the URL. so if I pass in `url.com?first_name=xyz&last_name=abc` then with my gem I could call `MyGem.first_name` and `MyGem.last_name` to call the respective attributes.

Comment: Ok, see my edits then...  Should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Awesome! And in terms of syntax, does it make most sense to include a class within your module, or to make the entire gem a class?

Comment: Usually gem classes are within a module named the same or similar to the gem itself, to keep their classes from conflicting with other similarly named classes.